# Bootstrap 4 display navbar-form on left and menu icon on right of collapsed navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am migrating to bootstrap 4 and reworking a lot of html and css to work with it. I added a navbar-form within my navbar and I want it to display on the left side and the menu icon to display on the right side when the navbar collapses.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
    /* Stackoverflow preview fix please ignore */
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .nav-link {
      padding-right: .5rem !important;
      padding-left: .5rem !important;
    }

    .dropdown-toggle.userLogin::after {
      display: none;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
```

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right ml-auto" type="button" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<a class="navbar-brand d-none d-xl-block navbar-styles">Nav Brand</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
      <a class="nav-link">Customers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Order</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
      <a class="nav-link">Prepress</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
      <a class="nav-link">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-xs-block d-sm-none d-lg-block">
      <a class="nav-link">Inventory</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item d-lg-none" uib-dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link" uib-dropdown-toggle id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="menu">
        More
      </a>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Prepress</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Print</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item hidden-xs-down">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Inventory</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item" uib-dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link" uib-dropdown-toggle role="menu">
        Office
      </a>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Vendor</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Purchasing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Build Items</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item" uib-dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link" uib-dropdown-toggle role="menu">
        Setup
      </a>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Company</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Employees</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Equipment</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Shipping</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Status</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">Quick Size</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">QuickBooks</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="ml-3 mr-auto hidden-xs">
    <form class="navbar-form col-xs-6" name="orderIDFrm" style="padding-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px" novalidate>
      <input class="form-control"  style="width: 85px; font-size:0.875rem" required placeholder="Order ID" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
    </form>
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav nav-bar-collapse ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item bg-dark" uib-dropdown>
      <a class="nav-link userLogin" uib-dropdown-toggle id="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
      </a>
      <ul uib-dropdown-menu style="right:0; left:auto;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link" >Employee Name</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <a class="dropdown-link">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block">
      <a class="nav-link fa fa-users navBtn"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
</body>
```

Screenshots are attached to show what I have and what I am trying to acheive.

[Current navbar in desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Xi1.png)

[Mobile Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ9mF.png)

Comment: You need the mobile toggle button in your code.

Comment: Your navbar doesn't collapse by default.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added my current code for the navbar I am building. Please let me know if you can see any problems. I am also including screenshots of what it currently looks like and how I want it to look. Also, I am using uib-collapse and when I switch to mobile view the navigation is toggled open. It does not close when I click a link in the open menu either. Any help is appreciated.